# Pass a mapped object to a different component in a different file

Tags: reactjs

I have an object called 'thought' inside a function in one file (myThoughts.js)

```
const thoughtsData = thoughts.thoughts;


function Thought({title, description, image, imageAlt, content, category, date, onThoughtClick}) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    onThoughtClick();
  }
  return (
  <Card sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', height: {xs: '200px', sm: '220px', md: '160px', lg: '100%'}, width: '100%'}}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          alt={imageAlt}
          image={image}
          height="100%"
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8} sx={{display: 'flex',justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <CardContent sx={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-start', flex: '1', padding: '16px'}}>
          <h5 component="h5" className={'thought-title'} style={{marginBottom: '5px' }}>
            {title}
          </h5>
          <p variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            {description}
          </p>
          <Button onClick={handleClick} size="small" sx={{fontSize: '0.7em', paddingLeft: '0', textAlign: 'left'}}>Read More</Button>
        </CardContent>
      </Grid>
    </Card>
    )
}

function MyThoughts({onThoughtClick}) {
    return (
        <>
        <h3 style={{marginBottom: '1em', color: 'white'}} className="timeline-item"><i className="fa-regular fa-lightbulb timeline-item" style={{marginRight:"10px"}}></i>Thoughts</h3>
        <Grid container spacing={1}>
          {thoughtsData.map((thought, index) => (
          <Grid container item key={index} xs={12} sm={6} md={12}>
            <Thought onThoughtClick={onThoughtClick} image={thought.image} imageAlt={thought.imageAlt} title={thought.title} description={thought.description} category={thought.category} date={thought.date} />
          </Grid>
          ))}
       </Grid>
        </>
    )
}

export default MyThoughts;
```

When a user will click on a button in a single Thought I want to pass along the thought's props (title, description, etc) to a different component (thought.js):

```
function MyThought({onBackClick}) {
    const handleBackClick = () => {
        onBackClick();
    }


    return (
    <Grid container direction="column">
        <Grid container item direction="row">
        <Button onClick={handleBackClick} size="small" sx={{fontSize: '0.7em', paddingLeft: '0', textAlign: 'left'}}>BACK</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item direction="row" sx={{justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
            <div>Category</div>
            <div>Date</div>
            {/* Category and Date */}
        </Grid>
        <Grid container item direction="column">
            {/* Title, description, image, and content */}
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    )
}

export default MyThought
```

For reference, in App.js there is a default view and a blogview, so that "MyThoughts" are always visible but "MyThought" will be visible when the user clicks on a single thought

```
<div className="App">
      {currentView === 'default' ? ( 
        <Grid container sx={{height:'100vh'}}>
          <Grid container item xs={12} md={3} direction='column' sx={{backgroundColor: '#4040cd', color:'white', padding: '2rem', position: {md: 'sticky'}, left: {md: '0'}, height: {md:'100vh'}, boxShadow: {md:"1px 0px 2px 1px #ccc"}}}>
            <SideContent/>
          </Grid>
          
          <Grid container item xs={12} md={6} sx={{padding: '2rem', overflowY: {md:'auto'}, height:{md:'100vh'}  }}  >
          <MainContent />
          </Grid>
          <Grid container item xs={12} md={3} sx={{backgroundColor: '#40CD87', color:'white', padding: '2rem 1rem', overflowY: {md:'auto'}, height:{md:'100vh'}, boxShadow: {md:"1px 0px 2px 1px #ccc"}}}>
            <Grid item>
            <MyThoughts onThoughtClick={handleThoughtClick}/>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    ) : (
    <>
    <Grid container>  
      <Grid item xs={12} md={9}>
        <MyThought onBackClick={handleBackButtonClick}/>
        {/* THOUGHT COMP */}
      </Grid>    
      <Grid container item xs={12} md={3} sx={{backgroundColor: '#40CD87', color:'white', padding: '2rem 1rem', overflowY: {md:'auto'}, height:{md:'100vh'}, boxShadow: {md:"1px 0px 2px 1px #ccc"}}}>
        <Grid item>
          <MyThoughts onThoughtClick={handleThoughtClick}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
      </>
    )}
        
    </div>
```

What is the best approach to handle this situation? Thanks!

I tried setting a state so that the onThoughtClick will pass the thought object but keep getting undefined.

Comment: You could try creating a ```useEffect``` that has a dependency of the stateVariable you're using, which will then execute ```onThoughtClick()``` when that stateVariable changes.